# SQL - Counting INTs from a VARCHAR field

Tags: sql-server

I have the following scenario. The VARCHAR field could have only 1 of the 2 values:

```
'12345 - some random text'
'87654321 - some random text'
```

I want to do select only the INT values and using this following query I am nearly there but am missing one key component:

```
SELECT
  CASE 
     WHEN (ColumnName LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%')  
           then SUBSTRING(ColumnName ,0 ,CHARINDEX('',ColumnName )+6)  
     WHEN (ColumnName LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%')  
           then SUBSTRING(ColumnName ,0 ,CHARINDEX('',ColumnName )+9) 
     ELSE (NULL) END 
FROM dbo.TableName
```

Actual Result:

```
12345
87654
```

Expected result:

```
12345
87654321
```

Please could anyone point out the one simple thing I'm missing?

Comment: Do LEFT until the first space character, cast the result to integer.

Comment: Or, just switch item order, longest like first...

Comment: Consider refactoring the schema.  If this sort of thing (two data fields packed into one field) is frequently needing separation, make them into two separate fields.  It is easier and far faster to concatenate two fields when needed than to search for a delimiter within a compound field.  The two field approach is directly indexable, the single field is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to fetch the leading integer value, you can search for the space and take everything before that:

```
select left(ColumnName, charindex(' ', ColumnName) - 1)
```

You can use `cast()` to convert this to an integer, if you like.

Based on your problem description, the field always starts with an integer followed by a space.  If this is not the case for some values, then you will want to use `case` to validate the format.

And the reason you are not getting what you want.  The conditions are in the wrong order.  The longer integer matches the first condition and the `case` stops there.

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
SELECT
  CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX((ColumnName , '-', 1))
FROM dbo.TableName
```